# Do not trigger build when creating new branch from Gitlab issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use Gitlab on gitlab.com and the issue tracker. 
Each time I have an issue, I create a new branch on the button inside the issue, but this triggers a new build (pipeline) in CI.
I don't want this because this branch is coming from master and doesn't need to be built.

How can I achieve that ? Is this a gitlab-ci.yml modification or a repository related configuration ?

Comment: Did you ever find a valid solution? I'm having the same issue and no good fixes so far

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Commit message we can avoid building for the newly created branch on GitLab CI/CD pipeline

```
Build Branch(master):
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[master\].*$/
  script:
    - echo "master branch"
  #  - sleep 60 | echo "hello master"
  # when: delayed
  # start_in: 3 minutes
  interruptible: true

Build Branch(release):
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - /^build_.*$/
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[build\].*$/
  script:
    - echo "release branch"
  #  - sleep 60 | echo "hello release"
  # when: delayed
  # start_in: 3 minutes
  interruptible: true
```

The branches will trigger when the commit message has start with [master] or [build]

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in [this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15170) you can avoid this behavior by the following configs in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      changes:
        paths: ['*']
        compare_to: refs/heads/master
      when: always

test:
  script: exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KrysGo for referring to that issue, was really helpful.

Was reading through all the issue page, and a better working config is the following, as you can see someone [posted](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15170#note_1133365836) further down in the issue they found and edge case that is fixed with the following:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      changes:
        paths:
        - '*'
        - '**/*'
        compare_to: refs/heads/main
      when: always
```